# get unique id, get latest date, get highest number and lowest number python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

This is an example of my data

| ID | purchaseDate | numOfItemsPurchased |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 12-10-2023 | 2 |
| 12 | 12-01-2023 | 34 |
| 56 | 24-03-2020 | 12 |
| 23 | 23-12-2012 | 1 |
| 23 | 23-05-2012 | 3 |
| 23 | 23-06-2012 | 4 |
| 24 | 12-10-2023 | 24 |
| 38 | 23-02-2012 | 21 |
| 16 | 12-10-2023 | 34 |
| 54 | 02-09-2020 |  |
| 54 | 24-03-2020 | 19 |

I want to extract the highest and lowest purchaseNo for each 'ID' and the dates they were made.
the expected result should look like:

| ID | maxPurchaseDate | maxPurchaseAmount | leastPurchaseDate | leastPurchaseAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 12-01-2023 | 34 | 12-10-2023 | 2 |
| 56 | 24-03-2020 | 12 | 24-03-2020 | 12 |
| 23 | 23-06-2012 | 4 | 23-12-2012 | 1 |
| 24 | 12-10-2023 | 24 | 12-10-2023 | 24 |
| 38 | 23-02-2012 | 21 | 23-02-2012 | 21 |
| 16 | 12-10-2023 | 34 | 12-10-2023 | 34 |
| 54 | 24-03-2020 | 19 | 02-09-2020 | 11 |

Please how do I get this done?

I tried this code:

```
details = data.groupby('ID').min()['purchaseDate']
```

But I get a KeyError: 'purchaseDate'. I have double checked to be sure the column was not misspelled. and I have made sure to fillna(0)

I also tried doing it this way:

```
details = data.groupby('ID').min()['numOfItemsPurchased']
```

It doesn't throw an error but I don't know how to add more columns to it

I have tried this code:

```
data.groupby(['ID']).agg({'purchaseDate': [np.min,np.max],
                          'numOfItemsPurchased' : [np.min,np.max]})
```

then I get a TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Make sure to `df["purchaseDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["purchaseDate"], dayfirst=True)` then, you can use `out = df.groupby("ID", sort=False).agg(["min", "max"])`, and last but not least, `out.columns = out.swaplevel(axis=1).columns.map("".join)` to flatten the column names (*with optional* `out = out.reset_index()`)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
def fn(x):
    mx, mn = x["numOfItemsPurchased"].idxmax(), x["numOfItemsPurchased"].idxmin()
    return pd.Series(
        {
            "maxPurchaseDate": x.at[mx, "purchaseDate"],
            "maxPurchaseAmount": x.at[mx, "numOfItemsPurchased"],
            "leastPurchaseDate": x.at[mn, "purchaseDate"],
            "leastPurchaseAmount": x.at[mn, "numOfItemsPurchased"],
        }
    )

# convert to datetime if necessary:
df["purchaseDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["purchaseDate"], dayfirst=True)

out = df.groupby("ID", sort=False).apply(fn).reset_index()
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   ID maxPurchaseDate  maxPurchaseAmount leastPurchaseDate  leastPurchaseAmount
0  12      2023-01-12                 34        2023-10-12                    2
1  56      2020-03-24                 12        2020-03-24                   12
2  23      2012-06-23                  4        2012-12-23                    1
3  24      2023-10-12                 24        2023-10-12                   24
4  38      2012-02-23                 21        2012-02-23                   21
5  16      2023-10-12                 34        2023-10-12                   34
6  54      2020-03-24                 19        2020-09-02                   11
```